# Считается ли нормой наследование множество -> элемент множества?

Tags: ооп

Подскажите пожалуйста, считается ли нормой в программировании наследование по принципу множество -> элемент множества? Например, у меня есть класс "кольцо многочленов с целыми коэффициентами", и я хочу от него наследовать класс "многочлен с целыми коэффициентами".

Answer (score 1):

Да это считается нормой. В этом вся суть наследования – класс-наследник реализует спецификацию родительского класса. Я бы даже сделал класс "кольцо многочленов с целыми коэффициентами" абстрактным и от него уже наследовал все частные случаи.

Answer (score 0):

Стоит быть аккуратнее с таким наследованием, потому что элемент множества может быть экземпляром класса, представляющего множество, а не производным от него классом.

Например, класс, представляющий людей с определенным набором свойств и экземпляр - конкретный человек. Такой человек уникален и вряд ли нужно от него наследовать что-то.

В Вашем примере можно рассматривать *многочлен* как производный класс *кольца многочленов*, хотя я сам бы использовал (и рекомендовал бы Вам) класс, представляющий кольцо многочленов с некоторым контейнером, содержащим эти многочлены и операцией добавления нового многочлена во множество, представляющее кольцо, с соответствующими операциями проверки нового многочлена на принадлежность кольцу (их 6, насколько я помню). Тут, правда, рассматривается, что у Вас конечное множество многочленов.

В случае использования наследования стоит помнить о следующем:

1. Вам надо определиться с типом наследования, т.е. означает ли оно *реализован посредством* или *является разновидностью*.
2. Рассмотреть альтернативы наследованию, например, использование композиции.
3. В Вашем примере для *многочлена* может использоваться множественное наследование, т.е. не только от кольца, но и от другого класса.